# Find out if line is empty in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using this code to check if the caret is on an empty line inside a textarea. It works well but has a single flaw: If you start a line with some text and finish it with a space, the code thinks that the line is empty; this is not true. I don't care about lines as a result of word wrapping.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jZN5w/

```
$('#area').on("keyup change focus", function() {
    if( this.value.substr(0,this.selectionStart).match(/(?:^|\s+)$/)
     && this.value.substr(this.selectionStart).match(/^(?:\s+|$)/)) {
        console.log("empty");
    } else {
        console.log("has stuff");
    }
});
```

This will log "has stuff"

The above line will log empty while this will log "has stuff"   This will log empty if I end the line with a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expressions don't look for empty lines, but for spaces.

```
$('#area').on("keyup change focus", function() {
    if( this.value.substr(0,this.selectionStart).match(/(?:^|\n|\r)\s*$/)
     && this.value.substr(this.selectionStart).match(/^\s*(?:\n|\r|$)/)) {
        console.log("empty");
    } else {
        console.log("has stuff");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jZN5w/6/

Comment: Thanks, one issue with this, though, is it treats empty spaces as "has stuff". Is that avoidable?

Comment: Basically, I want to treat nothing and white space as an "empty" line, while anything other than whitespace as a none empty value.

Comment: I updated the answer and the fiddle. Now it ignores whitespace. ;)